# Huge screens used behind stages

Tags: led

I always wonder what screens are used as backgrounds during most of the stage performances? Most of them are as huge as 50ft high and around 100's of feet wide. I can assume they are LED screens but last year while I was looking for LED billboard I was told that it consumes a lot of energy and needs a dedicated transformer and are very heavy to keep transporting it from one place to another.

[image: LED screen]

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just old fashioned rear projection screens?

Answer (score 1):

Typically they're Barco video walls. [These](http://www.barco.com/ebooks/media_entertainment/Projection_IP_catalog/index.html) look like the ones I saw a lot. They're HD and a 9'x9' section was around $1 Million USD last I heard.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, these are LED screens.

[image: LED screen closeup]

Implementations vary, but essentially, they're made up of *millions* of LEDs, usually surface mount ones. The resolution might be 1000x600 (600,000 pixels) but each pixel consists of either 3 or 4 LEDs. One red, one blue and two green (or sometimes two red and one green).

A rough calculation shows how much power these things consume. Assume each LED draws 5mA at maximum brightness, and that all are at half brightness.

```
  600,000 pixels x 4 LEDs x 2.5mA
= 6000 A
```

Let's say that the LEDs drop about 2v:

```
  6000A x 2v
= 12kW
```

12kW isn't that much power really. A couple of kettles will consume that much power.